# RxJava doOnError vs onError

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am try to use the following code

```
initLocalSettingsIfNeed()
                            .andThen(initGlobalSettingsIfNeed(configuration))
                            .doOnComplete(callback::onSuccess)
                            .doOnError(throwable -> callback.onError(throwable.getLocalizedMessage()))
                            .subscribe();
```

But I have exception

> The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the
> subscribe() method call.

I guess I am not using this methods correctly, I thought can replace `doOnComplete` `doOnError` with observer inside `subscribe()` method, I am wrong?

Comment: that's the expected behaviour. Try with `onErrorComplete`, if you want to swallow the error

Comment: No, i need to handle the error, this approach is wrong because doOnComplete() return new Single?

Comment: no it is not because of that. `doOnError` in not a replacement for `onError`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding your original question, you have to know that `doOnError` is not a replacement of `onError`:

> Actually there’s one key difference between them. doOnError() basically only triggers its callback, then passes down the encountered errors to the down stream. **So if the whole stream is subscribed without the onError callback in subscribe(), your app will crash by OnErrorNotImplementedException.**
>
> **The onError callback in subscribe() in the other hand does consume the
> errors.** That means, it will catch the errors, and let you handle them
> without re-throwing the errors by itself.

About the warning you mention in one comment:

> This approach is working, but i have warning 'the result of subscribe
> not used', as i know this need to be disposed automatically when
> onError or onComplete is called, is there way to avoid this warning? – Pavel Poley

A good approach is that your methods inside your `Repository` return a `Observable`, and then you can subscribe to them in your `ViewModel`. Then, in every `ViewModel` class you can have a member variable with a `CompositeDisposable` where you can add the disposable of each subscription to the Observables returned by your repository. Finally, you should override the `onCleared` method to dispose all the disposables stored in the `CompositeDisposable`.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MyRepository myRepository;
    private final CompositeDisposable disposables;

    @Inject
    public MyViewModel(MyRepository myRepository) {
        ...
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
        disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        ...
    }

    public void callObservableInRepository() {
         disposables.add(myRepository.myObservable()
                              .subscribe(onSuccess -> {...} , onError -> {...}));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        disposables.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: the blog link is dead

Comment: @tenprint probably taken down by the person writing it, but the relevant information is quoted in the answer

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
initLocalSettingsIfNeed()
    .andThen(initGlobalSettingsIfNeed(configuration))
    .subscribe({completed->
        callback.onSuccess()
    },{throwable->
        callback.onError(throwable.getLocalizedMessage())
    })
```

Comment: This approach is working, but i have warning 'the result of subscribe not used', as i know this need to be disposed automatically when onError or onComplete is called, is there way to avoid this warning?

Comment: you can add it for example to  CompositeDisposable() and dispose it after it is not needed anymore. Eg   disposables.add(wrapped above code) and then disposables.dispose()

Comment: but i am not using it in activity, i am using it in repositories without lifecycle

Comment: Repostory usage logic should be handled in Model when using MVP or ViewModel when using MVVM

Comment: so it is not safe not to use result of disposable? event if it simple request onComplete onError?

Comment: in my case i using few repositories in top level component to encapsulate some async requests, so in this case i need to make the top level component lifecycle aware?

Comment: It depends on what kind of Observable are you using, if it is for example Single is completely safe to use it without disposing because it is emitting only one time. That what I am using for repository